# nested SelectOneMenu JSF 2.1

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am developing a web application using JSf2.1.
I am following tutorials to code a selectOneMenu (drop down list box).

I need to have 2 dropdown boxes(A ad B) but essentially call the same ajax listener function which would do some computation with the choice A and B...

So, can we have nested selectOneMenu like this?

```
<h:form id= "ourForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu value= "#{bean.valA}"...>
       <f:selectItems ... />
        <h:selectOneMenu value= "#{bean.valB}"...>
             <f:selectItems ... />
             <f:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}" render="ourForm"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

And the bean listener method:

```
public void Listener{

//use valA and valB


}
```

Well, I tried doing the above but the page shows me a warning:

*the form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry.Suggestion enclose the necessary withing*

I tried without the nesting by calling the same listener on each selectOneMenu but I get same random behaviour..i.e: when I choose elem 1 of A retaining the "prev" choice on B, box B randomly updates its choice to default and vice versa!

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax. You need to understand that JSF generates HTML code. A `<h:selectOneMenu>` generates a `<select><option/></select>`. A nested `<h:selectOneMenu>` as in your attempt would generate `<select><option/><select><option/></select></select>` which is completely [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) HTML (and thus inherently also completely invalid JSF).

You're not terribly clear on the concrete functional requirement, but I understand that you want to show a child menu only on certain selection of a parent menu? In that case, use the `rendered` attribute and refer it in `<f:ajax render>`.

Here's a rough kickoff example, which can if necessary be more simplified (e.g. without the need for `renderMenuB` property, depending on the concrete functional requirement which you didn't tell anything about).

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedValueA}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableValuesA}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.handleChangeA}" render="menuB" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="menuB">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedValueB}" rendered="#{bean.renderMenuB}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableValuesB}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.handleChangeB}" render="ourForm" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)